# Converting time zones yields same timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I have a DateTime object in PHP.  Here it is:

```
$base = new DateTime('2013-10-21 09:00', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
```

When I call `$base->getTimestamp()`, I get, as expected: `1382360400`.

In my project, I am using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), and when I tell moment this timestamp is in "local time", it works fine:

```
// Correct :)
moment.unix(1382360400).local().format('LLLL') // Monday, October 21 2013 9:00 AM
```

The problem is, all other dates in my app are in UTC (except this one), so in my JavaScript code I have this:

```
var theDate =  moment.unix(timestamp).utc();
```

For all other dates, this works, but not this one.  `1382360400` is in "local time", not UTC.  I figured a call to `setTimezone` would fix that, so I did `$base->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));`.

Calling `var_dump($base)` returns me:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2013-10-21 13:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

This looks correct, but when I do `$base->getTimestamp()`, I get `1382360400` again!  That's not right!  I obviously don't get the right date.

```
// Incorrect :(
moment.unix(1382360400).utc().format('LLLL')  // Monday, October 21 2013 1:00 PM
```

How can I get PHP's `DateTime` to return me the timestamp in UTC?  I expect to get `1382346000` from `$base->getTimestamp()`, which is what I get when I do:

```
$UTC = new DateTime('2013-10-21 09:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $UTC->getTimestamp();
```

So, how can I convert my `DateTime` object to UTC and get the timestamp I want?

```
// Correct :)
moment.unix(1382346000).utc().format('LLLL')  // Monday, October 21 2013 9:00 AM
```

(PHP Demo: https://eval.in/56348)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps don't have a time zone. DateTime objects obviously internally store the timestamp, and not the date&time. So when you changed it's time zone, the same timestamp remained, but your date&time changed. When you started it was 9 hours, and after changing the time zone it was 13 hours.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to "convert" the timestamp.  I need a solution, or at least a workaround.

Comment: You could calculate the time zone offset of both timezones using `DateTimeZone::getOffset()`, subtract one from another and add the result to the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks!  `$base->getTimestamp() + $local_tz->getOffset($base);` returned me `1382346000` :-D DEMO: https://eval.in/56365

Comment: @RocketHazmat: or just stop using timestamps. You can send datetime in string format with timezone offset, moment will accept it, like `moment("2013-10-20 04:30 +0100", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");`.

Comment: @Glavić: So, instead of trying to "convert" the timezone, add it into the date string and let moment figure it out?  That's not a bad idea :)

Comment: @Glavić: That seems like less work than doing `+ $local_tz->getOffset($base)`, thanks.